# Firebase UI gradle Failed to resolve 'com.firebaseui.firebase-ui:0.2.0'

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

Trying to add firebase UI gradle dependancy but android studio say's

```
Error: Failed to 'com.firebaseui.firebase-ui:0.2.0'
```

Want to use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: Can you show the entire gradle.build for your app? It should include `dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.0'
}` Note that you should also use the latest version (0.3.1). See the [repo README](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#installation) for details.

Comment: 0.3.1 worked but for some reason com.firebaseui.firebase-ui:0.2.0 is still not working and please update this new version on github project also.

Comment: I updated the read me on https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI/ right after I commented. But I also tested wth 0.2.0, which worked fine too.

Comment: oops, may be some problem with my android studio but I wasted more time adding 0.2.0. Anyway now 0.3.1 working fine getting hands on FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

Add updated firebase UI gradle dependancy,it is working.

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it worked for me by copying the following in the build.gradle(Module:app):

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
```

So, my dependencies function looks like:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'}
```

Hope it to be useful!